# VScode Unity intellisense not working on a specific project

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Laptop, Windows 11, Unity 2022.1.24.f1

The intellisense works on my other projects but not on the new project i just made. Same Unity version, same machine, same vscode extensions.

I've also tried unchecking the **Omnisharp: Use Modern Net** in vscode settings. I have .Net SDK 7.0, .Net Core SDK 3.1 and .Net Framework 4.7.1 installed on my machine.

Comment: When I have this problem, most of the time it works to close the window and reopen it (command-shift-W, command-shift-N, select the workspace/folder from the "recent" list).

Comment: @frankhermes it didn't work for me. Thanks btw

Comment: This problem happened to me so often I just got work to pay for Jetbrains Rider for me. With the added bonus of it making life way easier for setup in Linux and Mac if thats a concern for you. Sounds like you would prefer to stick with VS code but I find there are so many causes of this bug you end up working your way through a list of 10 different fixes to find the one that is for you.

Comment: Finally fixed it. Re-installed C# extension and it started downloading Omnisharp. Omnisharp couldn't find an MSBuild instance. So i downloaded both MSBuild and MSBuild tools. Now its working.
MSBuild tools: [link](https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vs_BuildTools.exe)

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed a really similar issue using Unity 2021.3 and Visual Studio Code. There was a recent update of VSCode that caused my intellisense to break across all projects.
What I did to fix my own issue is uninstall the old unity extensions for VSCode, and replace them with the extension created by Microsoft
Then, I switched my .Net version from "Standard 2.1" to "Framework" in the unity project settings.
Then I went to preferences -> external tools and made sure it was set to VSCode 1.8xxx
Then I clicked on "regenerate project files"
Opened up a script by double clicking within Unity
Sometimes it is still finnicky. I have to click between files sometimes to get intellisense to work now.